# Toggle a class for a new div but the one clicked

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I've got a very basic jquery code for adding a new class to an HTML element:

```
<script>
$('#sign-in').on('click', function() {$(this).toggleClass('display-none');
});
</script>
```

It adds the `display-none` class to the div container with an id of #sign-in when it's clicked. However what I want is to add this class to a div with another id. How is that possible?

What I want finally:

```
<div id="sign-in"></div> <!-- The div to be clicked -->
<div id="new"></div> <!-- The div I need to add the .display-none class to when the previous div is clicked -->
```

Comment: Use `$("#new").addClass("display-none");` Property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**addClass**](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
<script>
$('#sign-in').on('click', function() {$(this).toggleClass('display-none');
$("#new").addClass("display-none");
});
</script>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gTuVW/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('#sign-in').on('click', function() {
    $('#new').addClass('display-none');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
<script>
$('#sign-in').on('click', function() {
$("#new").addClass("display-none");
});
</script>
```

Hope this will help you...